# Junit for RESTTemplate Clients

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

I am trying to write Junit for one REST Webservice Client which uses RestTemplate.

Below is method call to **REST** Template:

```
final ResponseEntity<LogDateVO[]> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, LogDateInputVO, LogDateVO[].class);
```

In My Test Class I am trying some thing like below :

```
mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://abc.def.pvt:80/testOperations/api/traffic/logs/")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
    .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess("{ \"id\" : \"42\", \"name\" : \"Holiday Inn\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

I am unable to get the result back and not able to continue with this approach, i need some help in getting this.

My intention is when my `restTemplate` is called it should check for above expect and return success with some data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming That class under test has a method which calls `postForEntity` using RestTemplate. For more info check [this](https://github.com/jeffsheets/MockRestServiceServerExample)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class SimpleRestService {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String getMessage() {
        String result;
        String httpResult = restTemplate.getForObject("http://google.com",
                String.class);
        result = "Message SUCCESS result: " + httpResult;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Your Test class should will be like as below:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:aap.xml"})
public class SimpleRestServiceFunctionalTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private SimpleRestService simpleRestService;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMessage() {
        mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://google.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("resultSuccess", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

        String result = simpleRestService.getMessage();

        mockServer.verify();
        assertThat(result, allOf(containsString("SUCCESS"), containsString("resultSuccess")));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMessage_500() {
        mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://google.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withServerError());

        String result = simpleRestService.getMessage();

        mockServer.verify();
        assertThat(result, allOf(containsString("FAILED"), containsString("500")));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMessage_404() {
        mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://google.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

        String result = simpleRestService.getMessage();

        mockServer.verify();
        assertThat(result, allOf(containsString("FAILED"), containsString("404")));
    }
}
```